# Как создать полиморфную связь?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

По ТЗ клиент либо отдаёт счёт в управление аналитику организации, либо занимается им самолично. Тип осуществления управления описывается договором. 
Я сделал таблицу "Управляющий" (которая задумывалась супертипом) куда должен был идти либо код аналитика, либо инвестора. Но указывая код одного из них, я получаю ошибку о нарушении свзяи со второй таблицей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать
[image: Часть реляционной модели]

Comment: *По ТЗ клиент либо отдаёт счёт в управление аналитику организации, либо занимается им самолично.* Перефразирую. По ТЗ аналитиком по счёту является либо штатный аналитик организации, либо сам клиент. Что приводит к необходимости учёта в схеме факта, что любой клиент может быть аналитиком. Я уж не говорю о том, что клиент и штатный аналитик могут быть одним и тем же человеком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Как вариант.]

В принципе такие таблицы в основном читаются, а не пишутся и изменяются. Поэтому особо можно не заморачиваться, а сделать, как удобнее. Как вариант, при выборке данных по договорам, чтобы узнать кто все таки управляет счетом, можно воспользоваться конструкцией case:
    `select d.*
      , case dt.dogovor_type_id

            when 1 then a.name_analitik case 
            when 2 then i.name_investor end manager
    from dogovors d
    join dogovor_types dt on d.dogovor_type_id = dt.dogovor_type_id
    join dogovor_members dm on dm.num_dogovor = d.num_dogovor
    left join analitiks a on a.num_analitik = dm.num_analitik
    left join investors i on i.num_investor = dm.num_investor
where ....`
В таблице Dogovor_members 3 столбца с айдишниками. На логической схеме просто не видно , поэтому показал скрином.